# UIImageView doesn't respect autolayout

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout

I set up my `UIImageView` like this:

```
let imageSize: CGFloat = 140
let profileImage = RoundImageView()
profileImage.image = UIImage(named: "girl_0")
profileImage.clipsToBounds = true
profileImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
profileImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
profileImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
profileImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.GSBackground().cgColor
profileImage.layer.borderWidth = 4.0

addSubview(profileImage)

profileImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 18).isActive = true
profileImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
profileImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: imageSize).isActive = true
profileImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: imageSize).isActive = true
```

It becomes 325x325 instead of 140x140. How? At least the console should print that it breaks some constraint?

See how the "Debug View Hierarchy" looks: [image]

`<...RoundImageView: 0x11903e470; baseClass = UIImageView; frame = (117.5 18; 325 325); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1d023a700>>`

I've tried setting `profileImage.setContentHuggingPriority()` to 1000 for both axises, but doesnt work.

I've tried returning 140x140 in `intristicContentSize` for the `UIImageView`, but doesn't matter, it'll still be 325x325 (but say `140 (content size)`.

I've tried `.scaleAspectFit` instead of `.scaleAspectFill`.

I'm just puzzled.

For full disclosure, here's `RoundImageView`:

```
class RoundImageView: UIImageView {

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    layer.masksToBounds = true
    layer.cornerRadius = frame.width / 2
  }

}
```

Comment: Where is this code?  What is `self`? - I just tried your code and it worked perfectly; except I had to add `self.view.` in front of things like `addSubview` and `topAnchor` which leads me to believe that you are doing this inside another UIView subclass and that may be affecting the end result.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for the effort. I've actually solved it. When I was thinking about how to explain it again to you, it made me think. And found the line `    profileImage.sizeToFit()` in one place - which seems to have caused it. The thing was, it would layout correctly first time always for me as well - but second time I'd view it, the image would get stretched.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer. In one place - where I updated the view, I had `profileImage.sizeToFit()`, which left all constraint the same, but the image became bigger.

The left image is first layout - the second after calling `sizeToFit` in the `UIImageView`.

[image][image]